# Tableau Queries with JOINS and check for NULL are failing in ClickHouse

Tags: tableau-api, clickhouse

I am running Tableau connected to ClickHouse via ODBC driver. At first mostly any report request was failing. I have configured this tdc file https://github.com/yandex/clickhouse-odbc/blob/clickhouse-tbc/clickhouse.tdc and its actually started to work, however now some of the query requests with JOINS that contain check for `NULL` in `ON` are failing because of using `IS NULL` instead of `isNull(id)`

```
JOIN users ON ((users.user_id = t0.user_id) OR ((users.user_id IS NULL) AND (t0.user_id IS NULL)))
```

This is the correct way that works:

```
JOIN users ON ((users.user_id = t0.user_id) OR ((isNull(users.user_id) = 1) AND (isNull(t0.user_id) = 1 IS NULL)))
```

How to make tablau driver to send the right requerst?

Comment: Can you also try CAP_QUERY_NULL_REQUIRES_CAST?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions:

[This post](https://community.tableau.com/thread/290261) on the **Tableau Community** looks like it has similar symptoms as you describe. The suggested resolution is to wrap all fields as such `IfNull([Dimension], "")` thereby reducing the need, apparently, to have Clickhouse do the check of nulls.

The TDC file from Github looks pretty complete, but they might not have taken joins into consideration. The [GitHub commit](https://github.com/yandex/clickhouse-odbc/commit/7b7cb84ff351d22f87ba576a3f04fbacef826597) states that the tdc is "untested." I would **message the creator** of that TDC and see if they've done any work around joins and if they have any suggestions.

[Here is a list](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/odbc_capabilities.htm) of possible **ODBC Customizations** that can be added to *or removed from* your TDC file. The combination of which may take some experimentation, but they're well worth researching as a possible solution.

**Create an extract** before performing complex analysis. If you're able to connect initially, then it should be possible to bring all the data from Clickhouse into an extract.

**Custom SQL** would probably alleviate any join syntax issue because the query *and any joins* are purely written by you. After making the initial connection to ClickHouse, instead of choosing a table, select "Custom ODBC" and write a query that will return the joined tables of your choosing.

Finally, the **Tableau Ideas Forum** is a place to ask for and/or vote on upcoming connectors. I can see there is already an [idea in place for ClickHouse](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/6454). Feel free to vote it up.

Comment: Any luck here? If so, please upvote and apply green check/tick mark. If you were able to solve on your own please place an answer to your question. I'm curious if/how you solved this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure not to have any NULL values in the data, you can also use this proxy that I wrote for this exact problem.

https://github.com/kfzteile24/clickhouse-proxy

It kinda worked, for most cases, but it's not bullet-proof.